# No AJAX when user is logged in?

Tags: 8, commerce, ajax, authentication-authorization

I am developing an e-commerce site for one of our customers for the first time with drupal. It is going pretty good so far but there is a weird misbehavior where I have no idea on how to handle it in a drupal context.

What I am using:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.3",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "dev-master as 1.3.x-dev",
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
    "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^3.0",
    "drupal/bootstrap_barrio": "^4.22",
    "drupal/commerce": "^2.14",
    "drupal/commerce_shipping": "^2.0",
    "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
    "drupal/core": "^8.7.0",
    "drupal/field_group": "^1.0",
    "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
    "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
    "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
},
```

That is the require block with the selenium2-driver fix. (just FYI, not relevant for that question)

So I have a /shop page as view were I am using better exposed filters for the sidebar, ajax/autosubmit is enabled in the view/exposed-form.

When I have, for example, chrome in incognito mode and I am not logged in as user the AJAX functionality works 100% perfect. But when I log in as admin OR as any other user, the AJAX is broken in the shop page.

Do I miss an issue here? I am really stuck, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the console in your browser for errors? That would be the first place to look as you may have a JS error effecting logged in users

Comment: Yea, yesteday there was one with QuickEdit and ContextualLinks, but i uninstalled both and now its error free with the behaviour described above